# Using class constants in Zend_Config_Ini application.ini

Tags: zend-framework, zend-config

I've got several constants defined in one of my classes and would like to use on of them in my application.ini, is this possible?

```
logger.main.level = \My\App\Logger::WARNING
```

This does not seem to work, it just parses it as a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the value of a constant in your `application.ini` you need to define the constant in the `/public/index.php` file (see the `APPLICATION_PATH`).

If you want to do it cleanly in your code I would eiter do it using the log level manually with the numeric value (assuming the constant is numeric as in Zend_Log) since this value is not likely to change or do it in the index.php and define a new constant named something like `LOGLEVEL_WARNING` (you can then get the value of the constant statically from your class), which you will be able to use in the `application.ini` file like `logger.main.level = LOGLEVEL_WARNING`

My pick would be the numeric value in the `application.ini` file like this :

```
resources.log.stream.writerName = "Stream"
resources.log.stream.writerParams.stream = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/logs/application_" DATESTAMP ".log"
resources.log.stream.writerParams.mode = "a"
resources.log.stream.filterName = "Priority"
resources.log.stream.filterParams.priority = 4
```

Take a look at `APPLICATION_PATH` and `DATESTAMP` which are constants that I have defined in my index.php

Answer (score 2):

I believe that PHP's `parse_ini_file()` function only has access to constants in the global space and not in the class space.

I haven't been able to use `My_Class::MYCONST` or `My\Class::MYCONST` in any .ini file.

Answer (score 0):

You can define constants in your application.ini file and then call them with the code below in controller.

```
public function init() {
    //Getting constants from application.ini file
    $registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
    $this->_constants = $registry->app_config->constants;
}
```

where your constants are defined in application.ini file like below

```
;My Constants
constants.MY_CONSTANT="value"
```